# php serverside geocoding with googlemaps returns status OK but nothing else

Tags: php, google-maps, curl

I am trying to geocode on serverside using php. following is my code:

```
static private function curl_file_get_contents($URL){
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $contents = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);

    if ($contents) return $contents;
        else return FALSE;
}


public function preview(Request $request)
{
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=my_api_key&address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA";

    $resp_json = self::curl_file_get_contents($url);
    $resp = json_decode($resp_json, true);

    if($resp['status']='OK'){
        dd($resp);
    }else{
        dd('not ok');
    }
```

When I run this I status is OK and dd($resp); gets executed and it outputs just this:

```
array:1 [▼
  "status" => "OK"
]
```

I've looked at the example json responses here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

and there should be alot more that should be returned but in my case it does not get returned. I am not sure why, could it have anything to do with me running this locally, although in that case it should not return status: OK

I've fallowed the example here http://erlycoder.com/45/php-server-side-geocoding-with-google-maps-api-v3

Edit:
If I past this into browser directly

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=my_api_key&address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA

then it returns alot more data

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "USA",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4223664,
               "lng" : -122.084406
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4237153802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0830570197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.42101741970851,
                  "lng" : -122.0857549802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by adding

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check your server configuration and check curl is supported or not.
use this code for check your server configuration

```
 <?php
    function get_tls_version($sslversion = null)
   {
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check");
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    if ($sslversion !== null) {
      curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, $sslversion);
     }
    $rbody = curl_exec($c);
    if ($rbody === false) {
    $errno = curl_errno($c);
    $msg = curl_error($c);
    curl_close($c);
    return "Error! errno = " . $errno . ", msg = " . $msg;
    } else {
    $r = json_decode($rbody);
    curl_close($c);
    return $r->tls_version;
    }
   }
echo "<pre>\n";
echo "OS: " . PHP_OS . "\n";
echo "uname: " . php_uname() . "\n";
echo "PHP version: " . phpversion() . "\n";
$curl_version = curl_version();
echo "curl version: " . $curl_version["version"] . "\n";
echo "SSL version: " . $curl_version["ssl_version"] . "\n";
echo "SSL version number: " . $curl_version["ssl_version_number"] . "\n";
echo "OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER: " . dechex(OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER) . "\n";
echo "TLS test (default): " . get_tls_version() . "\n";
echo "TLS test (TLS_v1): " . get_tls_version(1) . "\n";
echo "TLS test (TLS_v1_2): " . get_tls_version(6) . "\n";
echo "</pre>\n";
?>
```

Comment: If curl were not supported it would not produce the mentioned output.